# split .nc file in R

Tags: r, cdo-climate

I have a file, clip_pr_day_GFDL-ESM2M_historical_r1i1p1_19810101-19851231.nc. It has 5 years data from 1981-1985. I want to split it into yearly data. I need 5 files rather than 1 single file. I am beginner at R and have installed cdo 1.6.4.
Could you please send me an script for this using CDO in R?
Thank you.

Comment: What is cdo? Could you expand on it? What does the file look like? Why would you do this in R rather than at the source?

Comment: It's Climate data operators. https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/

Comment: "cdo splityear infile" splits into yearly data.

Answer (score 0):

the CDO command is

```
cdo splityear in.nc out.nc
```

you can also call this from R using `sys`